# Win Rt change event for TextBox

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, prism

I have a screen that shows 2 collections.
On the left side, I display a list of sections. By default, the first section is selected. If you click on another section then that becomes selected instead.
On the right side, I have a list of associated questions for that section in a one to many relationships.

So each question belongs to a section and a section can have 1 to many questions.

Some questions are required to have an answer, and some are optionally answered.
To make it easy for the user to find the required questions, a red asterisk is displayed next to the answer textbox. When that question gets answered it disappears.

Also, I need to show an asterisk for each section where there are unanswered questions. Once they are all answered the asterisk for the section also disappears.

The visual tree is of this format;
SurveyPageViewModel - SurveyViewModel - SectionViewModel - QuestionViewModel

The code below shows the QuestionViewModel (which contains the answer property) and the XAML code is in a DataTemplate so I do not think there is a way up the Visual Tree to update the section.

So my (simplified) handler code for my answer property looks like this;

```
private string _answer;
public string Answer
{
    get
    {
        return _answer;
    }
    set
    {
        if (SetProperty(ref _answer, value))
        {
            this.IfQuestionSetCheckIfAnswered(this.IsRequiredOnScreenAnswer);
        }
    }
}

private void IfQuestionSetCheckIfAnswered(bool value)
{
    if (this.IsRequired && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Text) == false)
    {
        this.EventAgg.GetEvent<RequiredAnswerUpdatedEvent>().Publish(value);
    }
}
```

and my XAML for the question/answer;

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0, 0, 0, 5">
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" 
                         Text="{Binding Path=Answer, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                         MinWidth="300"
                         IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=IsReadOnly}" />
                <TextBlock Text="*" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Bold" 
                    Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=RequiredSignal}" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"
                    Visibility="{Binding Path=IsRequiredOnScreenAnswer, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            </StackPanel>
```

I am using Prism and the EventAggregator pattern to update the Selected Section which is in a different ViewModel.
Now this works except for one important issue. I only want to update the section once the page is loaded. Currently, this event is fired both when the page is loaded AND when the answer changes.
How do I get this to work so the load is ignored?

Answer (score 2):

> I only want to update the section once the page is loaded. Currently this event is fired both when the page is loaded AND when the answer changes.

I'd define a command to activate the update once the page is loaded

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ActivateCommand}" />
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The above requires the Behavior SDK on WinRT (or the NuGet [package](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/30/xaml-behaviors-open-source-and-on-uwp/) on UWP), alternatively you could handle the `Loaded` event in code behind and relay it to the ViewModel as well.

Then `ActivateCommand` is supposed to set a `bool IsLoaded` member of the ViewModel so that it can be tested within your `IfQuestionSetCheckIfAnswered` method.

Comment: interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors is not supported in WinRT

Comment: Maybe needs sdk, look for example at this [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/29c709d8-6ddb-4e19-b8c2-6a035b1bcb41/uwpwill-there-be-a-behavior-sdk-to-support-eventtriggerbehavior-invokecommandaction?forum=wpdevelop)...

Comment: Or just handle the `Loaded` event in code behind and relay the event to the view model?

Comment: The solution was to be found in the Loaded event. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If someone wants to post the answer you can get the bounty.